# Should Access-Control-Allow-Origin need to be domain specific

Tags: http

Infosec has recommended us to use this header :

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://domainA.mycompany.com,http://*.mycompany.com`

But I also own domain : `http://domainB.mycompany.com`

So, if i just use

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://*.mycompany.com`

Will this be enough ? or it needs to be domain specific ?

Comment: Wildcard domains are invalid, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server side code should read the `Origin` request header and if it pattern matches one of your domains (`http://*.mycompany.com`) then you can return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <domain>` where `<domain>` is the actual `Origin` given in the request.

So if your request header is

`Origin: http://foo.mycompany.com`

this will match `http://*.mycompany.com`

so you set

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.mycompany.com`

for this response.